# Custom js function 'Cannot read property 'zoom' of undefined '

Tags: javascript

After following a google maps tutorial on tuts+, I have decided to build few of my custom functions. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/346yhv9w/)

In the 'controlZoom' function I am trying to set up some custom controls however I cannot access the 'this.gMap':

```
    controlZoom:function(){
        var plusZoom = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-plus-sign')[0],
            minusZoom = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-minus-sign')[0],
            count = this.gMap.getZoom();
        plusZoom.addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.gMap.zoom(count++);
        });
        minusZoom.addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.gMap.zoom(count--);
        });
    }
```

i can access the following:

```
console.log(count);
```

but not inside the 'click'event.

I am calling my custom function here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/h2ydh55c/)

When I try to click I get the following error in the console:

'Cannot read property 'zoom' of undefined '

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'this' inside your event listeners is probably the plus/minus button that was clicked. You can fix this by using a 'self' variable:

```
controlZoom:function(){
    var self = this;
    var plusZoom = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-plus-sign')[0],
        minusZoom = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-minus-sign')[0],
        count = this.gMap.getZoom();
    plusZoom.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.gMap.zoom(count++);
    });
    minusZoom.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.gMap.zoom(count--);
    });
}
```

or using .bind:

```
controlZoom:function(){
    var plusZoom = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-plus-sign')[0],
        minusZoom = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-minus-sign')[0],
        count = this.gMap.getZoom();
    plusZoom.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.gMap.zoom(count++);
    }.bind(this));
    minusZoom.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.gMap.zoom(count--);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

These fixes assume that 'this' inside controlZoom is the object that has gMap! I think it is, because you say the this.gMap.getZoom() line is returning the correct count. So my two suggestions should both work, but if not, try debugging by adding

```
console.debug(this)
```

to check that 'this' is what you expect.

---

**A note about using ++**

++ is an operator, and count++ will increment count and return. But the value passed into the function will be that of count before it was incremented. You can convince yourself of this via the following console session:

```
var n = 0

function report(p) { console.log(p) }

report(n++)
0
```

You call the 'report' function with n++, which you would think might lead it to print out '1'. In fact it actually prints out '0'. This is because n is passed into report before it is incremented by ++.

In your case, the first time you call your zoom(count++) function, you are in fact calling it with the existing value of count, and then only afterwards is count incremented. So it appears as if you need two clicks to zoom in. The safe way to do this is:

```
    plusZoom.addEventListener('click', function() {
        count++;
        this.gMap.zoom(count);
    }.bind(this));
```

then you will be sure that count is incremented before you pass it to the zoom function.

Comment: already checked on his fiddle, this doesn't reference the prototype, which is where his gMap is defined, so the click event handlers aren't actually accessing gMap.

Comment: great, thank you guys. Something else is happening now, it seems like it takes 2 clicks for the setZoom to get fired any ideas why?

Comment: This is to do with how you are using ++. I will add a note, but if you call this.gMap.zoom(count+1) then it will work on the first click, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setZoom` method instead:

```
this.gMap.setZoom(count++);
```

And you need to save reference to `this` and remove `bind`'s:

```
var self = this,
    plusZoom = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-plus-sign')[0],
    // ...
```

and then

```
self.gMap.setZoom(count++);
```

It will work then.

Comment: agree, but it still doesn't work. For some reasons this.gMap cannot be accessed

Comment: But the problem seems to be that `this.gMap` is `undefined` (though there may be another problem with `zoom`/`setZoom()`).

Answer (score 1):

In the scope of the function, `gMap` is not defined. Undefined variables do not have any properties, thus your zoom property won't work.

`gMap` is currently only defined in your prototype, and the functions that are a part of it, such as your `controlZoom`. When you add the click event listener's, you're not passing in `gMap`, and those functions do not belong to the prototype, so `this.gMap` won't work.

You'd have to define `gMap` in a global, or reference it using the prototype `Mapster`.